# How to write this sentences in a work proposal?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, word-choice

I am writing a formal work proposal, and I have a question about how to list the items in the index of my proposal. Because English is not my first language (Spanish is), I'd like some help making sure I index these correctly.

For example, in my index, should I use:

- ***Description of the project*** or ***Project Description***
- ***Benefits of this proposal***  or  ***Proposal benefits***
- ***Preliminary schedule of the project*** or just ***Preliminary schedule***

Are there any rules or guidelines that would help me know the best way to set up my index for entries that could be listed in more than one way?

Comment: thanks for help me, sorry so where can I ask you this question?

Comment: Hi beth, welcome to ELL. Proofreading is Off Topic here, and you're getting quite close to that. But all your specifics are all essentially asking about the same thing, so it's "just about" okay. The answer is most Anglophones would use the short forms for section headings in a work proposal such as this. It's a summary for busy people, not an essay.

Comment: @FumbleFingers so the j.r answer is correct right?, do you know a site where I can ask this type of help?

Comment: @beth http://lang-8.com/ is a site where you can have your writing proofread by native English speakers.  In return, you can proofread entries written by people learning Spanish.

Comment: beth: I've taken the liberty to rewrite the question in a way that would be a better fit for this community, yet still give you the answers you need. Feel free to re-edit or leave a comment if you think I've missed the core of your question.

Comment: @beth: I agree with what J.R. said about those "general rules", but I don't think your question is *quite* "Off Topic", because you're only really asking one thing: *Is it okay to use short "ungrammatical" forms for section headings in a business proposal?* So what I'm saying is: feel free to ask about *specific items* here, but be careful to avoid posting a long complex sentence and asking *Does this sound okay?*

Comment: @J.R. haha you've just invalidated a couple of my comments! But I think we're probably all on the same page now.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: ...and some of my own as well. I just hope I got the gist of the question correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Risking to express a controversial opinion, I would say that technical documentation has slightly different priorities than normal texts. Being in I.T., I read and write tons of technical papers, and I always prefer **readability and text size versus formal grammar**.

Think for a moment, your reader is often a non-native speaker as well, but, most certainly, they are a **busy** person. Overuse of large grammar constructs may just increase the size of your writing, without adding any value.

No, I don't say your document should be ungrammatical. Instead, it must be based on keywords, the shorter the better (unlike my answer :-)
Let's review individual phrases (I took those from your original edit):

- *Description of the Project* vs. *Project Description* — are you really sure that *project* is strongly necessary? If you leave just *Description*, wouldn't it make your documentation more succinct? I think, it would; There's also special terms, *purpose* and *abstract* to denote sections containing verbose description of a project and its rationale;
- *Justification of the project* — I wouldn't use *justification* at all. It has [several meanings](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/justification), and you may confuse your reader. Alternatively, it may be *review*, *analysis*, or *clarification*, depending on the context;
- *Definition of the scope of the project* — there's a term, *Scope of Work*;
- *Bounding of the projects* — use *Special Requirements* or *Dependencies* instead;
- *Benefits of this proposal* — just a keyword, *benefits*, seems to be sufficient (indeed, if not *of this proposal*, of what then?);
- *Competitive Advantages* — it's a term by itself, stick to it;
- *Deliverables of the project* — *Deliverables* and *Artifacts* are standard terms;
- *Preliminary schedule of this project* — just *schedule*. Everyone understands that it your schedule is *proposed*, therefore it is subject for change, and, because of that, is *preliminary*;

Summarizing:

- Use keywords, [separate the wheat from the chaff](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/separate+the+wheat+from+the+chaff);
- Use widely approved terminology, don't [reinvent the wheel](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/reinvent+the+wheel);

Comment: thanks for answer If I want to say Aims of the project, it is ok?

Comment: @beth _Aims_ usually refers _roles_, where people belonging to each _role_ have their own _goals_ or _aims_. In a general descriptive context ("what problem this project is intended to solve?"), _Problem Statement_ sounds better to me. In addition to my answer, I would suggest [googling for a terminology](http://www.google.com/search?q=business+proposal+terminology) in your particular area of interest. Also, definitely look for [some questions](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/3945/writing-the-perfect-proposal) at PM.SE.

Comment: I think that aims is like objectives but more formal, so better user objectives or goal or problem statement?

Comment: @beth Your mileage may vary, and it highly depends on your business area. In I.T., I avoid using _aims_ due to the reasons I mentioned above (too vague if an acting party/role is undefined). Others use it extensively.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, for section headers, I would favor the briefer forms, such as: *Project Description, Project Justification, Project Scope, Benefits, Project Deliverables, Preliminary Schedule*, etc.

In an actual sentence, though, either form could be used; for example, either "Here is the preliminary schedule for this project" or "Here is the project's preliminary schedule" would be acceptable.

In an index, you need to take a best guess as to which word the readers will look for when they want to find the information. I would avoid starting any index entry with "Project", as your index would be flooded with entries under the letter P. Instead, I would use a form like this:

> **D**
>   Deliverables for the project
>   :
>   **S**
>   Schedule for the project, detailed
>   Schedule for the project, preliminary

It's not uncommon for an index to list multiple forms for an entry, but usually the page number is only given in one place (this makes the index easier to maintain should new information be added). So, you might consider using something like this, if you feel it would enhance the usability of the index:

> **P**
>   Project Deliverables: see *Deliverables for the project*

Comment: thanks for answer If I want to say Aims of the project, it is ok?

Comment: In the context of a formal proposal, I think _Objectives_ would be a better word than _Aims_, and I'd usually phrase it as _Project Objectives_ rather than _Objectives of the Project_ (although, in the index, I'd simply use _Objectives_). You could always add an entry in your index that says "Aims: see _Objectives_", too)

Answer (score 2):

Use the simpler forms whenever they are unambiguous. If it's a pair like *project description*, you're fine. But take *Project computer maintenance*: Projecting the maintenance of the computer? Maintenance of the project computer? Computer-aided maintenance of the project? Projecting computer-aided maintenance?

The longer forms are more unambiguous, so always use them whenever the shorter forms can be read more than one way.

Answer (score 0):

If the entire document refers to a single project, the use of 'project' throughout the document will seem redundant.

So your document could have the title of 'Project Proposal' and your index, or table of contents, could contain elements like 'Description', 'Scope', 'Roles', 'Deliverables', and so on.

There is an example [here](http://graduate.asu.edu/sites/default/files/apa_quick_reference_0.pdf) that talks about a particular organization's document style guidelines. It also provides a primary example as is devided into several sections with bold labels.  In this example, the writer refers to 'Headings/Subheadings' as opposed to 'Document Headings/Subheadings' as all the items in this document refer to 'Document' guidelines.

I hope this helps.