# Combining "one" and "they": When one learns, they have to

Tags: grammar, pronouns, grammaticality-in-context, grammatical-number, singular-they

Is it possible to use "one" and "they" in a single sentence like this:

> When one learns a language, they have to learn about the culture as
>   well.

even though each of this pronoun uses a different grammatical number?

Comment: I am about 100% positive that in your language whatever it is, that would not be grammatical. When one x, one y.

Comment: @Lambie So "When one learns a language, one has to learn about the culture as well." would be fine?

Comment: I feel like the pronoun should be definite when mentioned for the 2nd time.

Comment: I think this falls into the realm of *singular they*. See [*Grammatical number agreement in a complex phrase using singular “they”*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/2791/1423). Basically, both *one* and *they* are indeterminate in quantity and gender.

Comment: One is one. You ***cannot shift like that** when the ***pronoun refers to the same person(s) in both clauses***. When one [you learn] learns a language, one has to [you have] learn about the culture as well. This is about using the right pronoun. When **I** go to the movies, **I** like to eat popcorn.

Comment: Yes, you can do a person and then they. But if you are writing a formal thing, I would not. It's OK in informal texts and conversation: When a person like to swim, they [etc.].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idiomatic choices are

> When you are learning a new language, you...
>
> When one is learning a new language, one ...
>
> When a person is learning a new language, they ...

Comment: Is they now actually idiomatic for person?

Comment: **they** is used with **someone** so why not with **a person**.... https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to%20someone%20they%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en  "... if I wanted to talk to someone, they'd listen."

Comment: It is used colloquilly, but is an innovation of very recent decades because people don't like to use "he" or "he or she". My question was whether it is now so commonly used that it counts as idiomatic.

Comment: @JeremyC - Singular *they* isn't "an innovation of very recent decades"; it's been around for hundreds of years.

Comment: Indeed, @JeremyC, as Stangdon says. See the examples in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they#Older_usage).

Comment: @stangdon OK. If it's good enough for Thackeray...